# Issue with ftw and processes

Tags: c, linux

> Write a C program that uses two processes (not threads) to sort the
>   regular files in a directory and the sub-directories based on file
>   sizes.   The program spawns one process (i.e., child process) to scan
>   the directory and the sub-directories for regular files. When the
>   (child) process finds a regular file, it obtains the size, and sends
>   the size and the pathname of the file to the parent process through a
>   pipe or FIFO. The parent process sorts (in ascending order) and
>   organizes the size and pathname information. When the child process
>   finishes scanning, it notifies the parent process, and the parent
>   process prints out the sizes and pathnames of the files.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include <ftw.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

static int dirSize = 0;
char *dirPath = NULL;
static int dirInfo(const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb, int tflag, struct FTW *ftwbuf){
    dirSize = sb -> st_size;
    dirPath = fpath;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    pid_t processCheck[1];
    int i = 0;
    int pipes[1][2];
    char *directoryPath = argv[1];
    pipe(pipes[i]);
    processCheck[0] = fork();
    if(processCheck[0]==0){
        close(pipes[i][0]);
        nftw(directoryPath, dirInfo, 10, FTW_PHYS);
        write(pipes[i][1], &dirSize, sizeof dirSize);
        write(pipes[i][1], &dirPath, sizeof dirPath);
        close(pipes[i][1]);
        exit(0);
    }
    close(pipes[i][1]);
    int childProcessStatus;
    if(WIFEXITED(childProcessStatus)&&WEXITSTATUS(childProcessStatus)==0){
        int v;
        char * d=NULL;
        if(read(pipes[i][0], &v, sizeof v) == sizeof(v)){
            printf("%d\t" , v);
        }
        if(read(pipes[i][0], &d, sizeof d) == sizeof(d)){
            printf("%s\n", d);
        }
    }
    close(pipes[i][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

The program is only printing  4096     4096

Comment: Add the line `printf("%u\n", sizeof d);` after those other printfs. What does it say?

Comment: it is printing 8

Comment: but d is supposed to print the pathname

Comment: d should probably be an array of characters, big enough to hold the longest pathname you'll write. And your parent has to read the exact same number of characters that the child writes to the pipe. Pipes don't have message boundaries.

Comment: then what should I do

Comment: Prefix the message to the parent with its length (2 bytes?).  Read the length then the data.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof dirPath` returns you the size of the pointer, not the length of the
string. Because `read` and `write` don't have message boundaries as [Mark Plotnick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49184104/issue-with-ftw-and-processes#comment85375277_49184104) points out
in the comments, you would need to either declare a fix size for the string
(meaning parent and child use the same size) or the child writes the length of
the string and then the string. I'd go with the second one:

For the child:

```
size_t len = strlen(dirPath);

write(pipes[i][1], &dirSize, sizeof dirSize);
write(pipes[i][1], &len, sizeof len);
write(pipes[i][1], dirPath, len); // not &dirPath, otherwise you are sending
                                  // an address, not the string
```

and for the parent:

```
int v;
size_t len;
char *d=NULL;
if(read(pipes[i][0], &v, sizeof v) != sizeof(v))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid answer from child\n");
    exit(1);
}

if(read(pipes[i][0], &len, sizeof len) != sizeof len)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid answer from child\n");
    exit(1);
}

// don't have to worry about setting the
// \0-terminating byte
d = calloc(len + 1, 1);

if(d == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
    exit(1);
}

if(read(pipes[i][0], d, len) != len)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid answer from child\n");
    free(d);
    exit(1);
}

printf("child sent: dirSize = %d\n", v);
printf("child sent: dirPath = %s\n", d);
free(d);
close(pipes[i][0]);
```

Writing this

```
write(pipes[i][1], &dirPath, sizeof dirPath);
```

is a bad idea, you are sending an address of the pointer. This address is most
likely only valid in the memory of the child's virtual space, you don't have a
guarantee that the parent process has the same information at the same address
in the parent's virtual space, the parent might try to access memory that it is
not allowed to. You have to send the contents of the array or if you want to
avoid that, then you have to use shared memory.

One last thing, you are not `wait`ing for the child to end. You should do:

```
close(pipes[i][1]);
int childProcessStatus;
waitpid(processCheck[0], &childProcessStatus, 0);

if(WIFEXITED(childProcessStatus)&&WEXITSTATUS(childProcessStatus)==0)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: still 4096  and what ever the directory passed

Comment: it should print all the directories info and path

Comment: *still 4096 and what ever the directory passed* I have no idea what you mean by that. *it should print all the directories info and path* I've shown you how to write correct information from the child to the parent, use that as a base for your code.

Comment: @NShah Right now, your child process writes the size and path exactly once, and the parent reads it exactly once. To make the child write the size and path of every file, you may want to edit your `dirInfo` callback function to do that, since `nftw` will call it for every object that it finds. You then have to change the parent to read everything from the pipe and then sort it.